# Wrong result for code doing dynamic programming in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am solving a dp problem .The problem is that I have N dices; each of them has K faces numbered from 1 to K. Now I have arranged the N dices in a line. I can rotate/flip any dice if I want. How many ways I can set the top faces such that the summation of all the top faces equals S?

Now I am given N, K, S; I have to calculate the total number of ways.It is worthy of mention I have to print the result modulo 100000007.I have tried to solve this problem and write a code for this one but my code doesn't work for this case:800 800 10000 why? I can't understand .Can anyone explain the cause for which my code doesn't work. My code is here:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cmath>
#include<memory.h>
#define M 100000007
#define ull unsigned long long
using namespace std;
ull n,K,s,dp[1001][1001];
ull fnc(int num,int sum,int k)
{
   ull temp;
   if(num==0){
     if(sum==0) return 1;
     else return 0;
   }
   if(dp[num][k]!=-1)
   return dp[num][k];
   for(int i=1;i<=K;i++)
   {
       temp=temp%M+fnc(num-1,sum-i,i)%M;
   }
   return dp[num][k]=temp%M;
}
int main()
{
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    for(int t=1;t<=T;t++)
    {
      cin>>n>>K>>s;
      memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
      printf("Case %d: %lld\n",t,fnc(n,s,0));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you replace your C++ code with pseudocode? Not everyone is literate C++, and C++ is also rather verbose. Also explain what is the meaning of each cell in your table `dp`.

Comment: for dp[n][k] n means number of throw and k means face value of a dice.

Comment: And what is `dp[n][k]` supposed to contain? Also, all this should appear as part of the question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It's not at all clear that the problem is with the algorithm, rather than the implementation, so pseudocode might not cut it. (OTOH, translating the algorithm to pseudocode might help the asker figure out where the problem is.) But, in any case, "Please fix my code" is off-topic on CS.SE; it's reasonably on-topic at [SO], if an explanation of the expected behaviour of the code is added.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You can turn the same argument around: it is not clear at all that the problem is with the implementation, rather it could be with the algorithm. A good pseudocode will be almost indistinguishable from the algorithm in this case.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No you can't. With the code in the original C++, it may be possible to find bugs in both the algorithm and the implementation; with it in pseudocode, only bugs in the algorithm can be found. (Note that this train of comments come from the original location of the post on Computer Science SE. Obviously, Yuval wouldn't be suggesting replacing the code with pseudocode here on SO.)

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong subscripts for `dp`.

Consider how many ways you can get 800 dice, each with numbers from 1 to 800, 
to have the sum 10000 if you make the number 1 uppermost on the first die 
and you make 4 uppermost on the second die.

Now consider how many ways to have the sum 10000 if you make 2 uppermost on the first die
and 3 uppermost on the second die.

Those two quantities are the same: each is the number of ways to get 798 dice (with numbers 1 to 800) to have the sum 99995. *That* is the kind of quantity you want to memoize.
But you have not even allocated enough space in `dp` to store this kind of partial answer.

I also have to wonder why you are using `unsigned long long` rather than just `unsigned long`, since your answer is to be given modulo 100000007.  You should never have to
work with numbers that are even near the maximum value of a `signed long`.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset :

> The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s with the constant byte c.

Note it doesn't say "the constant unsigned long long c".

You have the value k and K defined in the same scope, which is infuriating.

You hard coded 1001 and -1 instead of giving them proper soft coded variable names.

Most of your variable names are 1 character long.

You have persistent behavior in a return statement.

You have absolutely nothing checking if the values of k, K, and num are within the proper range of dp, which is partially a consequence of hard coding 1001.

Spacebar is your friend, writingcodelikethisthatwehavetoreadisannoying.